# iOS - Dismissing view controller itself through delegate work once

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates, dismiss

I present `customViewController` and trying to dismiss itself through delegate. It works only for the first time. When I `presentCustomViewController` again, `view controller` appears but it cannot dismiss itself. But when I try to dismiss it via button it works every single time. Could you tell me what's the reason?

```
- (void)presentCustomViewController {
    CustomViewController *customViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CustomViewController"];

    customViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
    customViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    customViewController.delegate = self;

    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:customViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - CustomViewController

@implementation CustomViewController {
    NSURLSession *backgroundSession;
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    backgroundSession = nil;
    self.mailComposeViewController = nil;
    self.documentInteractionController = nil;

    [self startDownload];
}

- (void)startDownload {
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *backgroundConfigurationObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"myBackgroundSessionIdentifier"];
    backgroundSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:backgroundConfigurationObject delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    downloadTask = [backgroundSession downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_attachment.url]];
    [downloadTask resume];
}

- (IBAction)cancelButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    [downloadTask cancel];

    self.mailComposeViewController = nil;
    self.documentInteractionController = nil;

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - CustomViewControllerDelegate

- (void)viewController:(CustomViewController *)viewController {    
    [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    NSLog(@"%@, %d", viewController, [viewController isBeingDismissed]);
 }
```

Logs:

```
<CustomViewController: 0x100691390>, 1
<CustomViewController: 0x100691390>, 0
```

Comment: do you checked that viewcontroller is not nil while dismissing second time in that delegate method?

Comment: show us more code, perhaps the implementation of the button and some code from the viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear()

Comment: @R.Mohan I checked and it's not nil.

Comment: I dont see any reason why you are doing this? Cant you just dismiss from the itself?

Comment: @Tj3n Even if I dismiss from itself it's not working. Logs are the same. Furthermore when I call cancelButtonClicked instead of dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion it's not working.